# Wordpress Blog Intro

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, gif

I am trying to achieve an intro on my wordpress site that is similar to this:http://www.ltlproductions.ca. I want to implement the expanding horizon line at the intro to my page. I'm not exactly sure how this is implemented in the example, but im thinking it is just a GIF that runs and then fades into the homepage. Are there any plugins that would make this easy to achieve, or do I need to make the GIF and then implement the initial fade myself, any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the page is using a javasscript plugin called **QueryLoader**.

- You can read on it (and download it) on the [QueryLoader2 Github page](https://github.com/Gaya/QueryLoader2) and on [Gaya's homepage](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/),

there is all the instructions for how to use it on a web page.

---

But there are also specific wordpress plugins for preloading.

- I just quickly found UltimatePreloader [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-preloader/) and here is a [demo page](http://www.2klabs.com/updemo/demo2/).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The ultimate preloader plugin was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Glad to help. Note: as you are new to stackoverflow, you can accept an answer by checking the tick at its side =)